# Send data from arduino to server using GSM, TCP

Tags: gsm, datalogging, iot

My actual connection is like:
**Arduino -> GPRS(http)-> my server(php script)-> firebase <-android plotting app**

But it only allows to send some data once every 2 - 3 seconds (depending of ping to my server).

I need to send some data (18 bytes) but every 0.5 - 1 seconds

It is possible to send directly over tcp to firebase?
And also i thinked about this schema:

**Arduino(client) -> GPRS(tcp) -> my server(tcp socket) -> my database <- android plotter** 
but I don't know how to go about it, what server software i need to redirect recieved tcp packages to mysql.

Comment: you use AT commands on the unknown GSM module?

Comment: `allows to send some data once every 2 - 3 seconds` .... this indicates that there may be a bug in the PHP script

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection

Comment: @jsotola Or it takes a couple of seconds to establish a new connection.

Comment: this is m590e module, and i use simple AT commands. It uses http GET connection and script read data from url parameters. I close connection every GET request. 'void loop() {
value++;
  String dpa  = "/test.php?arduino_data="+(String)value;
strncpy(resource, dpa.c_str(), sizeof(resource)); //string to char
  http.get(resource); //starting get request
  Serial.println(err);
   http.stop();} //closing connection' using tinyGSM library, how to make from it persistent connection, removing "http.stop()" not working :C